# Latest Update will not boot on my computer rejects my password

Tags: updates

Latest Update will not boot on my computer rejects my password. The login screen looks tiny and it keeps returning to login screen after I key in my  password. I need to do a total reinstall of the os?

Comment: I've exactly the same problem :/

Comment: Do you have installed a custom made keyboard layout? The latest updates included one for the xkb-data package which overwrites the existing one. So maybe some buttons are now interchanged. :)

Comment: Maybe the keyboard layout is set to English. Look at [this picture](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fqph.fs.quoracdn.net%2Fmain-qimg-49bb0ab6c8bf1814766461ab3d3ceab0&f=1&nofb=1) and try writing your password following the bottom keyboard. If that works you can then change your layout back to the correct one from System Settings.